# To develop FAT file system and USB host mass storage by keil middleware 5 without rtx?

Tags: host, keil, fat, rtx

I am developing (with lpc 1768 ) FAT file system and USB host mass storage by Keil middle wares version 5.

In the uvision "manage runtime environment"says must to enable rtx.

I have two questions:

1. is it possible do that without rtx (by keil middle wares only)?
2. if the answer is no what is the reason?

Answer (score 0):

All Keil middleware use CMSIS RTOS threads. It has been created that way so it hides a lot of the complexity. All you need to know is the API functions not how its actually implemented.

Look at http://www.keil.com/pack/doc/mw/USB/html/_u_s_b__device.html#usbd_system_resources 
 and http://www.keil.com/pack/doc/mw/USB/html/usb_resource_requirements.html#usbd_res_req for configuring the RTOS